# Implementing country - state - city selection for a static html page

Tags: html, country, countries

we run a static web site

the web sites form submission is connected to a service for handling form data, and is then forwarded to another service to process the data and handle the requests. What we noted is that the country - state - city selection needs to be uniform, to process that data better. There exist lists like this, for example: https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

That means there is no non-unique values like if you give the user a text input he will once write "london" once " London'" or "i'm from london"

So a list that has unique values for the user input.

That would be no problem for a dynamic website, I load the country data, and on selection of a country, I deliver the available states, and if that passes, I give the cities. The problem is, this site is static, e.g. html.

So to have a similar experience one would need to send the entire country state list database to the client, which is overkill and somewhere like 10 MB.

Comment: So, what's the question? How to do this without loading 10MB of data?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a page with a list of all 50 states as hyperlinks. Each state would link to a page with every city in that state. That way instead of sending 10 MB of data you'd have 10 MB of webpages and users would select which ones they need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>HTML Unordered List</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <ul>
        <li><a href = "/html/Alabam/Cities.html"> Alabama </a></li>
         <li>Alaska</li>
         <li>Arizona</li>
         <li>Arkansas</li>
        <li>etc</li>
      </ul>
   </body>

</html>
```

Something like the above code would should work. Each list item is a hyperlink, but you'll need to put the relevant files in the href.